# C#: Sharepoint file download via MS Graph returns unauthorized

Tags: c#, azure, sharepoint, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to simply download a file from Sharepoint using a Microsoft Graph bearer token. I continue to get a 401 Unauthorized response. The application will be running from within Azure but is currently running locally while I am figuring it out. The code follows, with comments in place of potentially sensitive information:

```
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;

namespace SharePointFileDownload
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string tenantId = /*My company's tenantId, from Azure*/;
                string accessToken = await GetGraphBearerToken();

                string tenant = /*the name of the tenant on sharepoint*/;
                string siteName = /*sharepoint site name*/;
                string library = /*sharepoint library name*/;
                string fileName = /*filename of the test document*/;

                string fileUrl = $"https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{siteName}/{library}/{fileName}";

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

                    string graphRequestUrl = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/tenants/{tenantId}/drives/root:{fileUrl.Substring(fileUrl.IndexOf("/sites"))}:/content";

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(graphRequestUrl);

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        byte[] fileContent = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                        File.WriteAllBytes("file.docx", fileContent);
                        Console.WriteLine("File downloaded successfully.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Failed to download file. Error: " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        public static async Task<string> GetGraphBearerToken()
        {
            try
            {
                string clientId = /*Azure ClientId for the registered application*/; 
                string clientSecret = /*Azure ClientSecret for the registered application*/;
                string tenantId = /*My company's tenantId, same as in the main method*/;

                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

                var requestBody = new StringContent($"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={clientId}&client_secret={clientSecret}&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                var response = await client.PostAsync($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token", requestBody);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    // parse the responseContent to get the bearer token
                    Console.WriteLine("Bearer token: " + responseContent);
                    return responseContent;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error fetching bearer token: " + response.StatusCode);
                    return String.Empty;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                return String.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code was assembled from a variety of tutorials. It successfully grabs a token and returns it to the main method, but then I get a 401 Unauthorized response.

I have added many permissions to the Azure application being targetted by the ClientId and ClientSecret, including Microsoft_Graph/Files.ReadWrite.All and Microsoft_Graph/Sites.ReadWrite.All.

Anyone with Sharepoint and Graph experience tell me where this is going wrong? Or if the code can just be optimized in any way? Thank you so much.

P.S. Here is an example of the entire response I get, if that helps:

```
StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
  request-id: /*An ID, the same as client-request-id*/
  client-request-id: /*An ID, the same as request-id*/
  x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"South Central US","Slice":"E","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"004","RoleInstance":/*Not sure if this is private, but here is a comment anyway*/}}
  WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="", authorization_uri="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize", client_id=/*A ClientId that does not match the clientId variable I passed*/
  Date: Tue, 21 Feb 2023 16:55:47 GMT
  Content-Type: application/json
}
```

Comment: Did you add delegated or application permissions in Azure Portal? Based on your code you need application permissions.

Comment: decode the access token you got in `jwt.io` and check if it contained a `roles` claim which has correct api permission.

Comment: @user2250152 I am using application permissions.

Comment: @TinyWang  Thank you, that website is awesome. The token does contain the roles "Sites.ReadWrite.All", and "Files.ReadWrite.All"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I agree with both *@TinyWang* and *@user2250152*, you need to add API permissions of **`Application`** type while using **client
> credentials** flow.

But when I ran your **code** after adding **`Application`** permissions, it still gave me **Unauthorized** error.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have one SharePoint **document library** named **`TestDocLib`** having files like below:

[image]

I registered one Azure AD application and added same **API permissions** of **`Application`** type as below:

[image]

When I ran same **c#** code as you, I too got access token with **`Unauthorized`** error as below:

```cs
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;

namespace SharePointFileDownload
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string tenantId = <tenantID>;
                string accessToken = await GetGraphBearerToken();

                string tenant = <tenantname>;
                string siteName =<sitename>;
                string library = <documentlibrary name>;
                string fileName = <filename>;

                string fileUrl = $"https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{siteName}/{library}/{fileName}";

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

                    string graphRequestUrl = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/tenants/{tenantId}/drives/root:{fileUrl.Substring(fileUrl.IndexOf("/sites"))}:/content";

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(graphRequestUrl);

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        byte[] fileContent = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                        File.WriteAllBytes("file.docx", fileContent);
                        Console.WriteLine("File downloaded successfully.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Failed to download file. Error: " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        public static async Task<string> GetGraphBearerToken()
        {
            try
            {
                string clientId = <appID>; 
                string clientSecret = <secret>;
                string tenantId = <tenantID>;

                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

                var requestBody = new StringContent($"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={clientId}&client_secret={clientSecret}&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                var response = await client.PostAsync($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token", requestBody);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    // parse the responseContent to get the bearer token
                    Console.WriteLine("Bearer token: " + responseContent);
                    return responseContent;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error fetching bearer token: " + response.StatusCode);
                    return String.Empty;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                return String.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded the above access token, it has **`roles`** claim with both permissions that confirms token is **valid** like below:

[image]

To know where exactly the issue is, try to run **same query** in Postman and check whether you got same results or not.

In my case, I ran different **graph query** in Postman by including above access token and got file download link in **response** like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<siteID>/drives/<doclib driveID>/root/children/<filename>
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I copied the above **download link** and ran it in browser, file downloaded successfully like below:

[image]

To confirm that, I checked the same in File Explorer and found **`sri12.docx`** file in Downloads folder like below:

[image]

To run the **same query** in c#, you can make use of below code:

```cs
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

string tenantId = "<tenantID>";
string clientId = "<appID>";
string clientSecret = "<secret>";

// using Azure.Identity;
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var driveItem = await graphClient.Sites["<siteID>"].Drives["<driveID>"].Root.Children["filename.docx"]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: This looks very promising! I'm trying it out now and I think this is the right direction. I will let you know when I have more.

Comment: @AJL I'm not sure how to get driveId. Based on the question if you have file url `string fileUrl = $"https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{siteName}/{library}/{fileName}";` Also there is no code how to download the file. @Sridevi Could you please add the code how to download the file?

Comment: It took me a long time to find the correct Site Id, but once I did, the answer provided by @Sridevi worked perfectly for getting the file. Now just to figure out what to do with it! Thanks so much